# How to prevent demon slayers from murdering their own en masse?

Tags: magic, demons

- Set in 1000AD.
- Demon exists and are hunting people.
- People retaliate and become demon slayers.
- Demon drops crystal upon being killed.
- Crystal emanates magical energy. (Intensity follows inverse square law)
- Magical energy gives user superhuman abilities.
- Demon slayers exposed themselves to these energy.
- Crystal starts forming inside the demon slayer's body as exposure prolonged.
- Bigger crystal emanates more potent magical energy.
- Powerful demon slayers possesses much bigger crystal then the ones being found on the demons.
- Surgical removal of these crystals is impossible back then.
- Small crystal accelerates tissue healing by 3 fold.
- Medium crystal boosts muscles strength by 4 fold.
- Large crystal gives user super speed, 0-60mph in 5s.
- Side effect of crystal is the insatiable hunger for magical energy.
- Half-life of crystal is 1 year.

**Is there any measure to prevent the demon slayers from turning into the very demon they sworn to slay?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have humanity have done that, just make people killing bad or frowned upon, people will still do it, but they will be ostracized, and probably very powerful and feared (I'd imagine a gang business of sorts).

Comment: And *where* is this set?

Comment: Half-life applies only to crystals outside of the body? (So they build up while inside, and drain while outside?) Or do they form and then drain all while inside?

What is the reason for rejecting the obvious "human-forged crystals don't work for (or damage/drain/kill) humans"? You want crystals to be crystals, regardless of their host?

I could propose things, but "insatiable hunger" makes this pretty tricky without more information. Oh, one more: is it ok if some demon slayers do turn, if in practice it's not common?

Comment: @sfink: half-life applies to all crystals even those inside the bodies of the demons, also it would take decades for a crystal to vanish since the half-life is in years not minutes or hours ;D

Comment: Do you need to prevent ALL demonslayers from turning murderous or only the majority. the later is easy, because demon slayers are still human and thus still have morals but the former is all but impossible because as humans some will do evil things for bad reasons. as advice you mingth want to leave the option since that gives you more story to work with if there is a moral aspect and a a few villains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Crystals are Magical and know when a Kinslaying has happened**

There are many instances in various lore of Magical beings or people with Magical properties getting severe adverse affects when killing one of their own. One tradition IIRC is that Shapeshifters can only turn into animals, unless they kill one of their own, then they can turn into other humans (or something like that).

So first option is that if a Demonslayer kills another Demonslayer, there is a significant negative effect - for bonus creative points, make said negative effect tempting that a few do.

**The Crystals positive effects only apply to those who are pure of Heart**

This is essentially the Paladin position - which is that all that power and strength comes from a place of Noble Spirit - A Demonslayer must act honorably in all things to reap the benefits of the Crystal - and intentionally murdering a fellow Demonslayer would be such a stain on their soul that the Crystals would no longer have any effect.

**Only Crystals from the same source can be combined**

A Demonslayer already has a Crystal inside of them, that cannot be surgically removed that was sourced from a Demon - A Crystal from a Demonslayer cannot be combined with a crystal from a Demon as they are from different sources *something something magic something feedback/resonance/conflict something* and they cannot be combined. To use the more powerful crystal from a Demonslayer, one would have to not have an existing Crystal... Good luck killing a Demonslayer to get their crystal when you are a puny un-augmented human.

**The Crystals give the Demonslayers the ability to sense Demonic prescence and those that have killed Demonslayers**

In short - A Demonslayer who killed other Demonslayers would be sensed by their fellows and immediately set-upon, disarmed, locked in a cell for a year (to let their existing crystals drain) before being handed over the the Courts for execution.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**:  The Slayer's own self-control and the fact that non-slayer humans likely don't have enough magical energy to satisfy the cravings.

**Joke Answer**:  Something a Demon Slayer can consume to ward off the side effects of their crystal, like wisteria tea.

**Longer Answer**:  The Slayer's Crystal forms while exposed to the demons and, what is more likely, their corpses.  As that crystal grows, they gain a need for more magical energy which directs them to slaying more demons, and more powerful demons at that.  Eventually, through age, cunning, or just bad luck, a slayer will meets their end at the hands of the demons that they pledged to slay.  A sad end, but ultimately safer for the Slayer.

Should they survive long enough, they find themselves with a crystal potentially stronger than any demons and not enough (powerful) demons to slay to get their magical energy fix.  Do you sequester yourself and ride out the cravings, cast a wider net for demonic prey, or succumb to your craving for magical energy?

The Slayer's Crystal, while driving them to feed on more magical energy, does not in and of itself mean that they will be a murderous cretin.  They are still human and know that most of their fellow humans lack that growing crystal inside them, meaning that they aren't worth harvesting.  And yet those same powerless humans are prey to a demon ...

Which leads nicely into the nature of the demons.  Them leaving behind a magic crystal is significant, likewise a human's ability to develop one in time -- they aren't completely different after all.  So what if by some action, either by a demon or by the slayer, that crystal could convert a human into a demon.  Regardless of the how, such an act would have to be intentional one

If a Slayer can sequester themselves, their crystal weakens and hopefully with it their cravings.  When their cravings are under control again, they can go out and kill more demons, which will cause that craving to rise again.  And does the cycle continue.

If they succumb to the hunger, then they will either go out in a blaze of glory against a demon they can't hope to defeat, or they will do something to trigger the crystal within them to turn them into a demon -- cursed to prey on the humans in a futile attempt to reclaim their own humanity.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical and historically plausible measure would probably be organisation. The demon slayers would want to pool their information and resources, and maybe get recognized as a valid organization by their sovereign. In 1000 AD it is highly likely they are devout followers of a deity or deities, and would want to involve their religious leaders—for their own protection, and for the resources and legitimacy of those leaders.

This demon slayer society will create increasingly elaborate rules, especially once it notices the power their more successful members attain. These rules will stipulate what kind of behaviour is unacceptable and how to deal with transgressions. Since transgressors will be stripped from their privileges and risk being prosecuted (and abandoned by their gods, as far as that's a personal reality), they are seriously dissuaded from letting the hunger for power get the better of them, and might even want to disclose any doubts or moments of weakness they have.

This won't assure not a single demon slayer will become a megalomaniac power-hungry killing machine, but there will be more control over any tendency in that direction, and it is more likely similarly skilled slayers are able to prevent, restrict, or minimize the terror of their (more) evil kindred. Divide and conquer.